# NameError - undefined local variable or method `user_details' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x0000000381bde0>:

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a basic Sinatra app when posting form details. I'm getting this error, especially when running on Heroku

> NameError - undefined local variable or method `user_details' for #:

Mye post method:

```
  post "/" do
  user_details = UserDetails.new(params["name"], params["email"])
  if user_details.valid?
    begin
      worksheet.insert_rows(worksheet.num_rows+1, [user_details.to_row])
      worksheet.save
      erb :thanks
    rescue
      erb :index
    end
  else
    erb :index
  end
end
```

View:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group<%= 'has-error' if user_details.errors.include?(:name) %>">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="<%= user_details.name %>">
            <% user_details.errors.full_messages_for(:name).each do |message| %>
              <span class="help-block"><%= message %></span>
            <% end %>
          </div>
</form.
```

Logs say it can't find the `user_details` variable in the first div block/class.

Any ideas?

thanks.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Thanks!</h1>
        <p>We'll let you know when our platform is ready. Stay tuned!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `user_details` a a local variable, which is not available in the view. Two options:

1. Define an instance variable `@user_details` and use that in the view.
2. Define a local variable `user_details` (as it is now) and render the view, passing the variable: `erb :thanks, locals: {user_details: user_details}` (or `erb :index, locals: {user_details: user_details}`, not sure where the error comes from)

Comment: Amazing, thx tbuehlmann. Unfortunately the thanks.erb file is not rendering on Heroku. Locally it works, but not when deployed to Heroku. I saved the file in views/thanks.erb. Relevant code see above.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you provide a repository that I can push to Heroku and test with?

Comment: sorry, just had a short git introduction, here the repo
https://github.com/johnsmith1212/12
thx in advance!

Comment: Phew, yeah, can't setup that. What's the actual error you get on Heroku?

Comment: unfortunately no error in the logs, but it's not sending the data to the google sheet and it's also not rendering the thanks.erb file. What do you need to test it?

Comment: hi tbuehlmann, any news on this? I really appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: Try removing the begin; rescue part and check for exceptions. Also, does it work from irb on Heroku?

Comment: unfortunately no error, I think the app can't access the google sheet, hence I'm trying now to rewrite this part but so far I'm not successful.


`def worksheet
  @session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key(@credentials)
  @spreadsheet ||= @session.spreadsheet_by_title("one-page-sinatra-app")
  @worksheet ||= @spreadsheet.worksheets.first
end`

Comment: also:

`@credentials = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(
  client_id: ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'],
  client_secret: ENV['GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY'],
  scope: [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/",
  ],
  redirect_uri: "http://example.com/redirect")`

Comment: found the error, it was the private key file! cheers for your help!